Saving barcode number in database that is generated with the logic
The barcode number required to generate the barcode is generated logically in the backend and is not a random number
Example: 1025683256. In this number first 4 digits are category_id, last 2 digits are counter_id, middle ones are product_id.
Each product has 5 counters - 12, 34, 56, 78, 90.
So for each product, I have 5 barcodes depending on the counter_id.
And each product defines a row in the database with 5 counter columns.
Now when I scan the barcode, I get this barcode number, and I want to search the item in database and display the item details.
So my question was should I save the barcode number in the database and search the item in the database via barcode number? Or just break the barcode number into its parts and search for the item in the database?

A barcode is a complete identifier for the row you are looking for. You should not disassemble it for the purpose of searching. Once the barcode is created, it should be stored as a complete unit and indexed for lookup.

There are actually many different barcode systems btw. Not just EAN13 and the like. I would store barcodes as strings just in case there is a leading zero

I am using Barcode of Code128. Its for maintaining inventory.

Ok. That doesn't change what I said, though.

@roganjosh - Thank you for the quick response. But my each row has 5 counters, which are distinguished by counter_id in example. Now, for each row I will have 5 barcodes depending on counter_id. Should I create a different table for the barcode?

What is counter_id sorry?

Just edited the question.
I have that specified counters for the products - It can be any one out of 5 i.e. 12,34,56,78,90.
So if my product is ABC, then stock can be:
ABC_12 - 5
ABC_34 - 5 and so on. But my SKU is ABC.
So, now there will be 5 different barcodes for ABC, depending on counters

This has nothing to do with barcodes or python, but with database design.

I still don't know what "counter" is. Is that a physical sales counter that the product is being sold on? And I agree with @JensSchauder here; we're veering way off a programming problem and just going into business process where it just won't be possible to answer

It is the counter_number, or consider as warehouse_number.
Agrred to @JensSchauder, my bad, it can relate to database design.
Should my database have different table for saving barcode number? or 5 different columns for the product row?

But, my main question was whether to save barcode number in database or not.
@roganjosh Thank you for the context. I will save the barcode number in database and index it

@roganjosh Judging from the question as it stands, the barcode doesn't just identifies a row in the product table, it also includes data from the product table.

@JensSchauder Yes correct.

If I understand you correct, you just want to find the product, which I assume is identified by the product_id.
In that case you should extract the product_id and use it to find the product in the database.
Searching for the full barcode would require you to search on 5 columns AND maintain this columns with redundant data.
Including the category_id would make your search brittle. What if a product is assigned a different category. Now you wouldn't be able to find it.
This is based on a couple of assumption I made, which you didn't explicitly state in your question:

product_id is actually the id of the product. If it isn't fix your column names.
category_id is actually the id of a category and used as a foreign key. If not, see above.

Update
From your recent comments I think I learned that you have multiple warehouses and for each warehouse which you identify with a counter_id and you have a stock amount which you name counter and you store these counters in  the product table.
While there might be (possibly good) reasons to do it this way, on its own it's a design flaw. You should have a stock table which has a composite id of warehouse_id and product_id and an amount column which holds the stock of the referenced product in the referenced warehouse.
If you only want to display the stock amount, you could query that table with product_id plus warehouse_id (formerly counter_id)
Or if you want to load product details and stock amount you can join  product and stock table and query by product_id and warehouse_id

Assumptions are correct. But, as it is for inventory purpose, I want to look for the stock.
So when I scan the barcode, it actually shows the stock of the product for the particular counter(warehouse). And thus each product is at the 5 counters, so I have 5 different barcodes.
Because of which, question raised that should I store all the 5 full barcode or just break the barcode get the product row from product_id and search for column from counter_id.

@Charmi in that case I would store all of the information. You don't want to have to recreate barcodes on-the-fly while searching, but you do have added information on where the product is actually stored which can also be used

@roganjosh wouldn't this be a redundant data?

I updated the question with an alternative approach, based on more stuff I think I learned about your domain and data model.

@Charmi no, absolutely not. If it exists in a particular warehouse then it should be tagged as such. Equally, you shouldn't be generating barcodes every single time you need them for a join or a lookup or... whatever. It's not duplicated because it's fundamentally different data - one column says where the item is physically stored and another gives it a unique identifier when scanned. As long as you follow decent database normalisation procedures, disk space is cheap and well worth it for this kind of thing

FWIW I have never known of a barcode that identifies a storage facility for the "same" product. Most of my last message is, therefore, theoretical.

Got it! Everything is clear now. Many thanks for answering the query.
